# Preventing the truncation of the Serialization stack trace

Tags: java, scala, serialization, apache-spark

I'm working with Scala `2.11` (Java 8 underneath) and Spark. Some operation related to an RDD I have is, I believe, throwing an Exception at runtime. However, that exception seems to be swallowed by Spark's attempt to serialize the entire Task. The Serialization stack trace that is output is quite long, and is being prematurely truncated with `... 114 more`. I'd like to know what those other 114 lines are, but I can't seem to find a way to prevent the truncation.

Across the internet the only references I've found to this were posted in 2009, touting the following as the solution:

```
-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true
```

Unfortunately 2009 was also the year that Java was acquired by Oracle, and as far as my experiments have shown, this no longer works.

**How does one prevent the Java serializaton stack trace from being truncated in 2016?**

Comment: Usually the X more lines are trunked because they are duplicated by another part of the stack trace. Do you have a "caused by" anywhere in your trace?

Comment: `Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: demo.DemoServiceActor`, which is very odd, because that is the parent class of the entire application. The RDD is in one of its methods, in a Spray endpoint.

Comment: In that case I bet the 114 lines are the same as 114 lines in the other part of the exception

Comment: That could be, however I still think it useful for the internet to know how to prevent the truncation.

Comment: "which is very odd, because that is the parent class of the entire application" Not really odd: it's a typical symptom of accidentally using a field or a method of this class (or some inner class) in a lambda which Spark needs to serialize. You need to pull any references like this into local variables outside of the lambda. Stack trace wouldn't help with this. "... 114 more" [is explained in Throwable.printStackTrace documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) and isn't serialization-specific.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Implicits struck again, where some implicits that were visible to the entire class were being silently passed to a funcion inside an `RDD.map`. Making them visible and local to the method fixed the problem.